# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in flowplayer

Tags: angular, flowplayer

I'm trying to integrate the flowplayer in my Angular 4 Project. I followed quick start docs(link:- /docs/player/quickstart). But I'm getting the Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘split’ of undefined in flowplayer.min.js

I couldn't find any solution… Is there a solution to this problem ??Like

Comment: could you share the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If this problem is with some sample code provided by a third party ... you may get a better answer contacting them directly.